# Retrofit 2.0 unit test cases

Tags: retrofit, robolectric

I was using retrofit 2.0 for making network call. I have require to write unit test case for the same. But i am not getting idea, how to write unit test case for retrofit call API. Please share some sample for retrofit unit test case with Robolectric

Comment: Anybody pls help and give idea how to write unit test case for retrofit2.0

Comment: Check the okhttp mock web server